# The nls() function in R

Tags: r, regression, nls

The hybrid New Keynesian Phillips Curve is:

[image: model]

After a few manipulations, we obtain the following estimable model:

[image: new model]

where *π* is inflation rate and *x* is a measure of output gap (= the cyclical component of GDP using the Hodrick-Prescott filter). The explanatory variables of the model *π* and *x* are observable.

I am required to estimate this model using nonlinear least squares; however, this model looks linear to me. Also, my attempts to use the `nls()` function in R have failed.

Also, my research on nonlinear regression led me to logistic population growth, but I'm not able to find a way to relate what I learnt to this exercise, especially when it comes to deriving the starting values.

Comment: we need a little more information/context, and a reproducible example wouldn't hurt.  In particular: are both pi and x observed, or just x?  What would a typical data set look like?  And why are you "required" to use nonlinear least squares -- is this homework?  (Offhand, it looks like a state-space model to me -- e.g. check out the `dynlm` package)

Comment: @BenBolker are there tools in the dynlm package for nonlinear regressions? I have been using it for linear regressions using time series data. And yes, pi and x are observable. And also yes, this is the last part of my homework. All the variables in the model were previously derived.

Comment: if (as your edited version says) `pi` and `x` are both observable, then this ought to be perfectly easily fitted with `lm()`.  The one argument for `nls`-fitting would be as one way of getting the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` directly, rather than having to back-calculate them (and use something like the delta method to approximate their uncertainties).  I would suggest that you (1) use `lm()` fit the model; (2) obtain starting values from the `nls` fit by back-calculating from those coefficients.  If you want help on homework you will definitely have to show us what you've already tried ...

Comment: I meant of course "obtain starting values **for** the `nls` fit" above ... the simplest way to get lagged variables for the linear regression is to make copies and prepend `NA` values/trim end values appropriately, e.g. lag-1 of `x` = `c(NA,x[-length(x)])`

Comment: If you do succeed in solving this problem yourself based on the hints above (or completely on your own), could you please post the answer here?

Comment: @BenBolker thanks to your help, I was able to solve the problem. Below, I provide a detailed walkthrough of how I went about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ordinary least squares (OLS) with the `lm()` function to estimate equation (2) in the question would lead to the estimation of the coefficients [image: coef1], [image: coef2] and [image: coef3].

On the other hand, using nonlinear least squares with the `nls()` function to estimate the equation would estimate values for the parameters 'a', 'b' and 'c', which are the parameters of interest.

The `nls()` function (nonlinear least squares) in R has two important parameters: First, the `formula` parameter and then the `start` parameter. Running `?nls` in R will provide some details; however, the gist is that the `formula` parameter takes in the expression of the non-linear model one wants to estimate (e.g. `y ~ a / (b + c*x)`, where 'y' and 'x' are variables and 'a', 'b' and 'c' are the parameters of interest) and the `start` parameter takes in starting values of the parameters of interest, which R will use in the iteration process (because nonlinear least squares basically iterates calculations until the best values for the parameters are obtained).

Below are the steps:

(i) Obtain the starting values of the parameters 'a', 'b' and 'c'

Here, I used the `lm()` function to estimate the coefficient of equation (2). I started by creating lagged variables to use in the function.

NB: 'y' refers to '[image: pi]'

```
y_1 = c(NA, head(y, head(y, -1) # variable 'y' lagged  by one time period
y_2 = c(c(NA, NA), head(y, head(y, -2) # variable 'y' lagged by two time periods
x_1 = c(NA, head(x, head(x, -1) # variable 'x' lagged by one time period
```

So, to estimate the coefficients of the equation, the following code was used:

```
reg = lm(y ~ y_1 + y_2 + x_1, na.action = na.exclude) # it is important to tell R to exclude the missing values (NA) that we included as we constructed the lagged variables
```

Now that we have estimates for [image: coef1], [image: coef2] and [image: coef3], we can go ahead and calculate values for 'a', 'b' and 'c' in the following way:

```
B = 1 / reg$coefficients["y_1"] # Calculates the inverse of the coefficient on the variable 'y_1'

A = B * reg$coefficients["y_2"] # Multiplies 'b' by the coefficient on the variable 'y_2'

C = B * reg$coefficients["x_1"] # Multiplies 'b' by the coefficient on the variable 'x_1'
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are then used as the starting values in the `nls()` function

(ii) Use the `nls()` function

```
nlreg = nls(y ~ (1/b)*y_1 - (a/b)*y_2 - (c/b)*x_1,
        start = list(a = A, b = B, c = C))
```

The results can be seen with the code:

```
summary(nlreg)
```

Thanks to Ben Bolker for providing the insight :)